# Avoiding shutdown hook

Tags: java

Through the following code I can play and cut and audio file.
Is there any other way to avoid using a shutdown hook?
The problem is that whenever I push the cut button , the file doesn't get saved until I close the application

thanks

```
void play_cut() {

        try {

    // First, we get the format of the input file
    final AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(inputAudio).getType();
    // Then, we get a clip for playing the audio.
    c = AudioSystem.getClip();
    // We get a stream for playing the input file.
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputAudio);
    // We use the clip to open (but not start) the input stream
    c.open(ais);
    // We get the format of the audio codec (not the file format we got above)
    final AudioFormat audioFormat = ais.getFormat();

     // We add a shutdown hook, an anonymous inner class.
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        // We're now in the hook, which means the program is shutting down.
        // You would need to use better exception handling in a production application.
        try
        {
          // Stop the audio clip.
          c.stop();
          // Create a new input stream, with the duration set to the frame count we reached.  Note that we use the previously determined audio format
          AudioInputStream startStream = new AudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputAudio), audioFormat, c.getLongFramePosition());
          // Write it out to the output file, using the same file type.
          AudioSystem.write(startStream, fileType, outputAudio);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
    // After setting up the hook, we start the clip.


     c.start();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// end play_cut
```

---

Actually , what I wanted to know is :
Do I really need a shutdown hook?

If I move these two code statements

```
AudioInputStream startStream = new AudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputAudio), audioFormat, c.getLongFramePosition());
AudioSystem.write(startStream, fileType, outputAudio);
```

somewhere else after   c.start(); I get an error :

> exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement -->catch(IOException e)

Do you think I can get the same results without resorting to the hook?

Comment: Can't you simply call the methods you already use in your shutdown-hook whenever you want?

Comment: The error you mention here is a compiler error, warning you that you catch an exception that is never thrown inside the corresponding try-block. The call to `AudioSystem.write` can throw an IOException, and when you move the call outside the try-block, that try-block cannot throw the exception. You have to move the complete try-catch-block instead of only the two statements.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all your comments are completely redundant, you just repeat the name of the various classes and methods you're using.

As for the problem, well your save code is in the shutdown hook which means "*do this when the application is about to close*" which naturally means that it won't save it until the program is about to close. So, move that logic away from the shutdown hook to whatever the logical place for it is - most likely at the end of the method, mayhaps in `final` block even - and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method

```
public static native shutdownWithoutHooks();
```

Create a headerfile of the method using `javah`.

Create a native c++-File calling

```
exit(0);
```

Compile and load the library using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().load("<absolute filename of the .dll/.so-file");
shutdownWithoutHooks();
```